# Insert more than 250 items in sharepoint list using javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am not able to add 365 days( date format: 01/01/2014) of year in a sharepoint list using javascript.
but it is updating list  when I enter range of 'for' loop = 250.
Please refer below code.

```
function DateIncrement() {
  var siteUrl = '/sites/..';
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Student');
  var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

  for (i = 1; i < 365; i++) {
    var myDate = new Date("01/01/2014");
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + i);
    var str = myDate;
    this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    oListItem.set_item('Date', str);
    oListItem.update();
  }                 

  clientContext.load(oListItem);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);

  function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {            
    alert("Complete");           
  }

  function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {
    alert("Failed");        
  }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The date must be specially formatted. In [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) I created a function that converts a JavaScript Date to the Sharepoint format.
The format should be: "year-month-day hours:minutes:seconds". So, for "31/Oct/2012" it must be "2012-10-31 00:00:00".

The function `toSPDate` looks like that:

```
function toSPDate(oDate) {
  var pad = function(p_str){
    if(p_str.toString().length==1){p_str = '0' + p_str;}
    return p_str;
  };
  var month   = pad(oDate.getMonth()+1);
  var day     = pad(oDate.getDate());
  var year    = oDate.getFullYear();
  var hours   = pad(oDate.getHours());
  var minutes = pad(oDate.getMinutes());
  var seconds = pad(oDate.getSeconds());
  return year+"-"+month+"-"+day+" "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds;
}
```

Note: SharepointPlus uses the Sharepoint web services. I'm not sure if you need to do the same with the Microsoft native functions.
Note 2: I read again your question but I'm not sure I understood correctly... If not, please try to explain again your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the only issue am facing is regarding the 'for' loop range. when I provide 'for' loop as for(i=1;i<=250;i++) the dates are being inserted in the list. But if I increse the range to 365  ,i.e, for(i=1;i<=365;i++), the script fails to update the list.

Comment: Maybe it's too much data for one request. With SharepointPlus I split each data into a block of 15. So one AJAX request is done for 15 items to insert. In your case it means 25 requests will be sent. Try installing Firefox + Firebug to watch the requests send to the server and the error returned by it. It's probably the reason. If 250 is OK, then you'll have to split in 2 your addition: one request from 1 to 250, and another request from 251 to 365.